# How to extract GMT and timezone from a date string?

Tags: javascript, regex, date

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
```

This results a string as "Mon Nov 30 2020 11:16:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)". How can I get only the `GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`. Is there any way to extract these values from date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy steps -

1. Get the date string
2. Search for the index of "GMT" in the date string
3. Get the substring starting from "GMT" till the end

Below is a snippet for your reference -

```js
var d = new Date().toString();
var finalD = (d.substring(d.search("GMT"), d.length));
console.log(finalD);
```

Answer (score 2):

For example using regular expression.

```
var str = 'Mon Nov 30 2020 11:16:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)';
var timezone = /(GMT.*\))/.exec(str);
alert(timezone[1]); // GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Or using `substr` (you know the length of substring before GTM)

```
var str = 'Mon Nov 30 2020 11:16:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)';
alert (str.substr(25)); // GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Comment: Thanks. But, why does the timezone returns as an array with duplicate values. Is it safe always to use the timezone[1] to get the result.

Comment: @amar: sure, I have there `[1]`. In `[0]` are all finded matches, than in `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. are single matches. If you have just this short string (and it isn't a substring in a logner text), `substr` would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

getTimezoneOffset() Method
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getTimezoneOffset());
```